# Flutter - How to make AppBar in video?

Tags: flutter

How can I make the AppBar in this video.

Video: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cE4Oy.jpg

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SliverAppBar`, here is an [example](https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-collapsing-toolbar-sliver-app-bar-14b858e87abe) for that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's custom scroll with sliver app bar in it